# How to add leading zero to day and month in pandas.core.series.Series object

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a large data set that does not have leading zero for the month orday. When working with datetime, it is expecting that the day and month will have a leading zero.

Here is the way the date is presented in my data set:
1/1/2023

How can I convert this to:
01/01/2023

- Tried to apply a format but it seems to only work for integers:
  print("{:02d}".format(number)) --> This works to add a leading zero for an integer
- Tried:
  merged_dfs["Date"] = merged_dfs.apply(lambda x: "{month:02}-{day:02}-{year}".format(month=x.month,day=x.day,year=x.year))

This returns an error: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'month'

- Tried:
  merged_dfs['Date'] = merged_dfs.ts_placed.map(lambda x: '{year}-{month:02}'.format(year=x.year,month=x.month))

This returns an error: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'ts_placed'

- Tried:
  merged_dfs["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(merged_dfs["Date"], format="%-d-%-m-%Y")

This returned an error: ValueError: '-' is a bad directive in format '%-d-%-m-%Y'

- Tried:
  merged_dfs["Date"]=merged_dfs["Date"].apply(pd.to_datetime, format="%d-$m-%Y")

This returned error:
ValueError: time data "1/1/2023" doesn't match format "%d-$m-%Y", at position 0. You might want to try:
- passing `format` if your strings have a consistent format;
- passing `format='ISO8601'` if your strings are all ISO8601 but not necessarily in exactly the same format;
- passing `format='mixed'`, and the format will be inferred for each element individually. You might want to use `dayfirst` alongside this.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['1/1/2023', '1/2/2023', '1/15/2023', '10/1/2023', '12/15/2023']})

df['Date_2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format = '%m/%d/%Y').dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')

df
```

Output:

```
         Date      Date_2
0    1/1/2023  01/01/2023
1    1/2/2023  01/02/2023
2   1/15/2023  01/15/2023
3   10/1/2023  10/01/2023
4  12/15/2023  12/15/2023
```

Answer (score 1):

Reusing @Scott's example, a format agnostic approach could be to use a regex and [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) to find the single digits and pad them:

```
df['Date2'] = df['Date'].str.replace(r'\b(\d)\b', r'0\1', regex=True)
```

Output:

```
         Date       Date2
0    1/1/2023  01/01/2023
1    1/2/2023  01/02/2023
2   1/12/2023  01/12/2023
3   10/1/2023  10/01/2023
4  15/12/2023  15/12/2023
```

Comment: I was able to get the expected results using the first method proposed from Scott! I had tried a similar command but added in a minus sign based off some comments I read online. Guess I should have tried it without the minus sign. Thanks!